# How do I fix my dead keys in Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, keyboard, keyboard-layout

My problem is whenever I type quotes on Snow Leopard 10.6.4, it waits for the next character typed, and turns it into another character instead of just typing quotes.

example:

[shift] + " a results in ä 
[shift] + " u results in ü

I don't want this functionality, I just want to type quotes normally, I don't need these characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are called [**dead keys**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key), that's because they seem dead when pressing but act later for diacritics.

Have you tried changing the Keyboard Layout and Settings in your System Prefernces?

Comment: after trying a few things out, I solved the problem:

I was using the "U.S. International PC" keyboard instead of just the "U.S." one. When I set my keyboard as "U.S." the problem was solved.

thanks for your answer :)